# How to download OneNote notes from SkyDrive to my PC?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I started using OneNote and storing my notes in SkyDrive associated to my Microsoft Account.

But now I want to download and store all of my notes on my PC and use them from there only.

I tried installing the SkyDrive and download all content that was on my SkyDrive, but it only downloaded some empty folders with my notebooks' names. They're just shortcuts to the OneNote Live app to my notebooks online. In other words, SkyDrive is no help. It doesn't download my notes in OneNote.

How else can I download them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to download anything because it is already downloaded!

When you connect the OneNote client to OneDrive, SharePoint or some other network location, OneNote caches a local copy and keeps the two in sync.

If you want to stop using OneDrive to keep the master version, right click on the notebook in the list of notebooks in OneNote, select properties and then "Change Location". You can put it wherever you like.

I have notebooks on OneDrive (actually I only now have a single notebook there to make use of the new API that is used by a variety of iOS apps for example), SharePoint (for business notebooks) and my home NAS (a Synology that has a Dropbox-like sync client).